# AngularJS and Ionic Framework: module is not available error

Tags: django, angularjs, module, ionic-framework

When loading my webpage, I get the following errors:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LFSTD' is not a function, got undefined

Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not defined
```

The webpage i'm loading has the ng-app attribute in the body tag, and a Ionic tag has the ng-controller:

```
<body ng-app="ia">
[...]
<ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="LFSTD">
```

"ia" and "LFSTD" are both defined in app.js. The webpage does load the following static files correctly

[image: network]

This is app.js:

```
angular.module('ia', ['ionic'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    controller('LFSTD', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
        $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
            $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
        };
    });
});
})
```

I've been struggling with this, lurking stackoverflow and ionic/angular docs for quite a while. It might be worth saying that my project uses Django. Any idea what might be causing these errors?

**Solution**

```
angular
.module('ia', ['ionic'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'create.html',
        controller: 'LFSTD'
     })
 }
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    controller('LFSTD', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
        $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
            $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
        };
    });
});
})
```

Comment: The module won't get created if you have a syntax error (like unexpected token)

Comment: are you sure your `ionic.bundle.js` is loaded?

Comment: @pankajparkar Absolutely, I added a screenshot to the question showing the network tab of the console. I also modified the question as I played around and am now getting different errors.

Comment: could you add your controller file code..

Comment: Can't I include my controller directly in app.js? Sorry, i'm very new to angular. The controller in only defined in app.js, you can see in the last block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the .controller part in app.js. I thought I could include controllers in a function, but no. It needs to be directly after the angular.module. See updated question.